# Multiple devices for one Firebase email authentication

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm using Firebase Auth to authenticate users in my iOS swift app, and I want to allow a group of friends to sign in from the same email and password. 
I couldn't find anything in the documentation about it. Is it possible? Is there's a limit for one authenticated user that may prevent 10-20 devices to be logged-in at the same time?
Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no limit for users using the same account, i have test accounts for some apps that everyone in the company uses. The only thing you should look out for is the daily limit if you're using Spark plan, since it has a limit of 100 multiple users connected.

Comment: Great! Thank you!